# A tabulation program on a given interval [a;b] with step c

Tags: c++

I developed a program to tabulate a given interval [a;b] with a step of c, and also find its largest and smallest value on this interval. I'm not sure if I have it right, so I wanted some advice. This code has a picture with a task condition.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvUeZ.png)

In the process of solving the given problem, apply the loop operator with a prerequisite. In the process of implementing the given task, assume that the argument of the function is identified as x, and the identifier of the variable responsible for the value of the function is y.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <clocale>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iomanip>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    double x, y, a, b, c;
    double max, min, max_y, min_y;
    
    max = -INT_MAX;
    min = INT_MAX;
    
    cout << "\n a:";
    cin >> a;
    
    cout << "\n b:";
    cin >> b;
    
    cout << "\n c:";
    cin >> c;
    
    cout << "\n a = " << a;
    cout << " b = " << b;
    cout << " c = " << c;
    
    y = a;

    while(y <= b){
        if(y > 1) x = sin(sqrt(y + log(y)));
        if((0 <= y) && (y <= 1)) x = M_PI + pow(cos(y + 1.2), 2);
        if(y < 0) x = y * log10(pow(y,2) +2) + M_PI;
        
        if(x > max){
            max = x;
            max_y = y;
        }
        
        if(x < min){
            min = x;
            min_y = y;
        }

        cout << "\n     x = " << setw(8) << x << "      y = " << setw(8) << y;
        
        y += c;
    }
    
    cout << "\n The largest value in the given interval is" << max << " at y = " << max_y << "\n";
    cout << "\n The smallest value in the given interval is" << min << " at y = " << min_y << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When entering the values a,b,c into the console, our program should tabulate the function (output to the console) and find the smallest and largest value in the interval. I have the program working, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I would like to hear some advice

Comment: Try to avoid `using namespace std`, it's a bad habit to get into. The `std::` prefix exists for a reason.

Comment: Prefer using `(x * x)` instead of `pow(x, 2)`.  The multiplication is usually much faster and more accurate.

Comment: Once you've tested the program and are pretty sure it's working, you can ask for improvement suggestions at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). I linked to the asking help pages because you'll want to read them to make sure you meet their question expectations.

Comment: why are you not sure if it is correct? Use a different tool to plot the function and you'll see. I like https://www.wolframalpha.com/. If you read a bit of documentation you can even use it to get the min / max directly

Answer (score 0):

Added small updates: 
Looks good overal

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //math.h == cmath
#include <clocale>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iomanip>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

void tabulate(double from, double to, double step)
{
    double max, min, max_y, min_y, x = 0;
    max = from; //they all start at 'from' anyway, its always best to set the max and min to first element of the array you're going through. They get overwritten anyway.
    min = from;
    for(double y = from; y < to; y += step)
    {
        if(y > 1) x = sin(sqrt(y + log(y)));
        if((0 <= y) && (y <= 1)) x = M_PI + pow(cos(y + 1.2), 2);
        if(y < 0) x = y * log10(pow(y,2) +2) + M_PI;

        if(x > max){
            max = x;
            max_y = y;
        }

        if(x < min){
            min = x;
            min_y = y;
        }

        cout << "     x = " << setw(8) << x << "      y = " << setw(8) << y << endl;
    }

    cout << "The largest value in the given interval is " << max << " at y = " << max_y << endl;
    cout << "The smallest value in the given interval is " << min << " at y = " << min_y << endl;
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    double a,b,c;

    cout << "a: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "b: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "c: ";
    cin >> c;

    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;

    tabulate(a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```